# how to bind again the click event for the button

Tags: javascript, jquery, bind

I have a button on which i am attaching a click event. I have to unbind it after i click on it, and later on in my code i need to bind that click event on it again. I tried binding it again but that does not works. I can't use jquery 'live'. Is there any way to create a custom bind function on click event and then again call it ?

```
$(".submitButton").click(function(e){
    //some functionality on click
    $(".submitButton").unbind('click');
});

//somewhere ahead in my code 
$(".submitButton").bind('click');
```

Apparently this isn't working. Is there any way to tackle this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your .bind call doesn't seem correct. You haven't specified a callback.

So start by writing a function:

```
function handleButtonClick() {
    //some functionality on click
    $(this).unbind('click');
}
```

Notice that inside the handler I am unbinding `$(this)` which is the element being clicked and not all elements with `class="submitButton"`.
and then:

```
$('.submitButton').bind('click', handleButtonClick);
```

and then later when you want to rebind:

```
$('.submitButton').bind('click', handleButtonClick);
```

and so on.

Comment: accepting this as the correct answer because of that "$(this)" point :)

Answer (score 3):

define your listener somewhere else:

```
function clickHandler() {
    //some functionality on click
    $(".submitButton").unbind('click', clickHandler);
}

$(".submitButton").bind('click', clickHandler);

//somewhere ahead in my code 
$(".submitButton").bind('click', clickHandler);
```

Answer (score 2):

When you use `.bind()` to bind an event handler it expects a function to be passed as well, since that's what will be executed when the event fires. Don't use an anonymous function, instead declare a named function and pass a reference to that when binding.

```
function handleClick(e){
    //some functionality on click
    $(".submitButton").unbind('click');
}

$(".submitButton").click(handleClick);

// somewhere else in your code (in reaction to some other event)
$(".submitButton").click(handleClick);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jQuery.one()`. Please refer below code.

```
$(".submitButton").one('click', clickHandler);
```

The first form of this method is identical to .bind(), except that the handler is unbound after its first invocation.

you can call it or bind it whenever it necessary.